# Make mecanim transition after a delay in Unity3D (2D mode)

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, transition, unity3d-2dtools

I'm using Unity's Animator to animate my character, I want an animation to start only if it lasts long enough.

*For example*: sometimes if my character goes on the ground and there's a little something on the way it makes my character ascend for a frame or two, but my **onGround** parameter of my animator still detects the change an make my character animating the **Flying** animation.

So in this case I want my animation to start only after a short delay like 0.1 sec, and only if the **onGround** parameter is still false, to avoid these little glitches.

Is there an easy way doing this? Or should I manipulate it from script? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution I'm using a float variable with the name **offGroundTime**. I set the value in every tick, increase it with `Time.deltaTime` if my onGround variable is false and set it to 0 if it's true. If the offGroundTime is bigger than 0.2, I turn on the flying animation, if it's lower, I turn on the idle animation.

Answer (score 1):

How do you do your transition to the Flying state, a boolean? If so you could try a float range and blend animation just after some point on your range, like 0.5F.

I can't open unity right now but I think even if it is possible to use just [blend trees](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html) configuration is a better way to have a solid scripted control.

*ps: just in case, if you are trying to make a jump state machine this is huge discussed in many threads and is not so trivial as it seems*

Comment: Yes I used a boolean, but you gave me a good idea. Unfortunately I cant use blend trees, since the animations contains different clips (it's a 2D animation BTW). But now I'm using a float variable as you suggested.